# FadeIn, FadeOut then do the same with another image

Tags: jquery

I want to fadeIn image, wait few msec and fadeOut image and I want to do this with few images, I also want to loop this. My idea was to do this with for each loop, but it doesn't work. I wrote this:

```
function showDiv() {
    if($('.header_img a:not(:contains(shown))').length) {
        var current = ($('.header_img a:not(:contains(shown)):first'));
        $(current).fadeIn(1500).delay(4000).fadeOut(1500);
        $(current).addClass('shown');
        setTimeout(showDiv, 1000);
    }
}
showDiv();
```

Edit:
A lot of thanks for all the answers :) However, I've made something on my own:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var current = ($('.header_img a:first-child'));    
    var counter = 0;
 var n = $(".header_img a").length;
function showDiv(current) {
    if(counter<n-1 )
    {
    counter++;
    $(current).fadeIn(1500).delay(4000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
    current=$(current).next();
    showDiv(current);
    })
}
else{
counter = 0;
$(current).fadeIn(1500).delay(4000).fadeOut(1500, function(){
    current=($('.header_img a:first-child'));   
    showDiv(current);
    })
}

  }
showDiv(current);
  });
```

... and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a callback when the animation is completed: http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var fader = {
    init: function() {
        this.firstLi = jQuery('#images ul li:first').attr('id'); 
        this.lastLi = jQuery('#images ul li:last').attr('id');
    },
    doFade: function() {
        this.currID = jQuery('#images ul').data('currLI');
        this.currLiStr = '#images ul li#' + fader.currID;
        this.nextID = (this.currID == this.lastLi) ? this.firstLi : jQuery(fader.currLiStr).next().attr('id');
        this.nextLiStr = jQuery('#images ul li#' + fader.nextID);
        jQuery(fader.currLiStr).fadeOut(3000);
        jQuery(fader.nextLiStr).fadeIn(2000);
        jQuery('#images ul').data('currLI',fader.nextID);
    }
}
```

Called like:

```
var firstLi = jQuery('#images ul li:first').attr('id');
    jQuery('#images ul').data('currLI',firstLi);
    fader.init();
    setInterval('fader.doFade()',10000);
    }
```